# javascript match implicit variable

Tags: javascript, regex, variables, match, implicit

I'm unable to determine if there is an **implicit variable** for match results in javascript.

The resulting code which I'm looking for is this:

```
if(line.match(/foo{bar}/)) {
  console.log(bar_variable)
}
```

the referenced ^ bar_variable should contain the match group result.
Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not. [`String.match()` returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> An `Array` whose contents depend on the presence or absence of the global (`g`) flag, or `null` if no matches are found.

So you could do something like:

```
if (bar_variable = line.match(/foo{bar}/)) {
  console.log(bar_variable)
}
```

To avoid a global symbol you could do something like this, but it does make it a bit uglier:

```
{
  let bar_variable;
  if (bar_variable = line.match(/foo{bar}/)) {
    console.log(bar_variable);
  }
}
```

As far as I know you can't do `if (let x = ...)` but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thank you, that actually looks like a somewhat solution,
the creation of global variable is painful though.

Comment: Updated to show how to avoid a global, but you are probably already aware.